# Get IP address of domain with Unicode characters?

Tags: php, unicode, ip

In PHP, how would I get the IP address of `www.mén.com` for example? I've tried `gethostbyname(), gethostbynamel(), dns_get_record()` but none of these work for Unicode characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert the domain name to its Punycode form before you can resolve it. You can do this using the [`idn_to_ascii()`](http://php.net/idn_to_ascii) function, part of the `intl` extension:

```
$domain = "www.mén.com";
$domain_ascii = idn_to_ascii($domain);
print $domain_ascii; // "www.xn--mn-bja.com"
```

Once you have the domain in this form, you can work with it normally, e.g. passing it to `gethostbyname()`.